# powershell exchange script output only works when typed manually

Tags: exchange, powershell

I'm typing the following command in exchange 2010 EMS and it works when I run it interactively.

```
$a = Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -server theName | fl name,activedatabasecopy,status,contentindexstate
Write-Host $a
```

If I call a script from within the EMS window that has the same command I get the following:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
```

Not sure why the same command is outputting differently. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that pipeline output is modified differently in a script vs manual command typing. I found the answer in the post below which mentions the use of "out-host".

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780815/exchange-get-mailbox-output-different-in-script-vs-command-line